# How to request the supervisor email from a researcher

Tags: email, collaboration, supervision

I am trying to contact a professor in another university in a different country for a potential collaboration. I only got the email that he uses on his papers, which he doesn't open as much because I emailed him a week ago and he didn't even open the email (I use a mail-tracking tool).

- Can I ask one of his students for a Gmail or something?
- If yes, What the correct way to approach the student?

Comment: A perhaps tangential comment - I disallow read-receipts in my email program, and avoid interacting with people who use them. It is a really passive-aggressive thing to do. Email is inherently non-real-time.

Comment: Have you considered that he did not respond because he is on a break, away at a conference or just busy and might get round to your email soon? A week is not long in time for academics - not compared to the classes that take priority...

Comment: Nobody enables receipt confirmation.

Comment: Woah.. I knew that I will get heat from mentioning that I used a mail-tracking tool, but I never expected that it will completely shift the feed-back I asked for. Well mailing has changed, people today to tend to not reply than to politely say 'no'. So personally, I prefer to know if he/she actually read the email or not so I can decide my next step. And in case if the next step is unclear for me I will ask questions like I did here, so worry not :).

Comment: @JonCuster You don't use a return receipt, you use a tracking pixel. Nearly all of the marketing e-mails you receive do this, advertisers have this stuff all figured out. I've seen this in some cold-call e-mails like the OP has done; if your client loads external HTML images by default (Gmail, Apple), you'll never notice.

Comment: Well it's because the return receipt is paid a feature for most email clients like Gmail. That's how important that feature is in the world of emails.

Comment: @user71659 - well, my security folks are really good, so that would not work on me...

Comment: that actually made me smile xD. I am a researcher in Computer Security. I do a lot of freelancing (penetration testing) for companies too, and almost every-time during the first meeting (or during my initial assessment) I get the same sentence "my security folks are really good", "we have a high level of security here", "our team is a security expert". I am not insinuating anything, but.. good for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, do not try to find an alternative email address. If it is the address he put on articles, it is probably his professional email and that is the one you should use.

One week is very short and from what you say, there is no emergency.